# User Input Using Pop Up :In Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I want to take input from the user and want to print it to the text field like OTP, I want to take OTP from user then want to print in specified field.

Scenario: I Want to pass genrated OTP for logging in to Red Bus while using some pop up window.

Trying with this **Code**:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("mobileNoInp")).sendKeys("8874141555");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[5]")).click();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('otp').value = ");
```

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: I want  one pop up window where user can pass the generated OTP  and passed . OTP generated should be print in Specified field(Get OTP text field.)

Comment: please provide your html element code for that pop up

Answer (score 0):

use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`

```
    final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    String otp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialog, "Please enter your one time password", "Enter otp", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    // continue with entered otp value entered by user
```

[image: looks like this]